# I'm having URL File-access errors when using OpenDir. Why?

Tags: php, opendir

```
<?php

   $pathname = "http://myserver.com/projects/" . $_GET['project'] . "/"; 

   if ($handle = opendir($pathname)) {

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

          if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && (strpos($file, '.jpg',1))    ) {

            $photo= $pathname . $file;
            echo "<image src=\"" . $file . "\">";

          }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    } 
 ?>
```

There is my code. All I'm trying to do is pass a URL parameter like "project=Flowers", and have PHP open a folder called /flowers/ and return ALL of the .jpg images inside it.

However, when I run my code, I get these errors:

> **Warning: opendir() [function.opendir]: URL file-access is disabled
>   in the server configuration in
>   /nfs/c01/h03/mnt/73283/domains/myserver.com/test.php on
>   line 3
>
> Warning: opendir(http://myserver.com/projects/flowers/)
>   [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: no suitable wrapper could be
>   found in
>   /nfs/c05/h02/mnt/76383/domains/kulthouse.com/html/staging/work.php on
>   line 3**

Any ideas why this won't work??

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas why this won't work??

Because you're using **filesystem** function to access a web **URL**

So, I'd make it

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/projects/'.basename($_GET['project']).'/'
```

basename() is very important here, not letting anyone to browse any directory on your disk

Comment: So should I just be using relative paths..? If my PHP script lives in a completely different folder, does opendir start at the webserver root? Or do I need to do "../../projects"?

Comment: @Ninjection If I were you, I'd use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable to mark the point where filesystem path meets virtual web-server directory system. Added code to the answer.